# SOAP service on Java returns incorrect types in Response

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I use a third-party server written in Java.
WSDL is taken with the style of rpc/literal.

Connection to the service is initialized as follows:

```
private static MLPortChannel GetMerlionClient()
{
    BasicHttpsBinding binding = new BasicHttpsBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
    binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 4096000;
    EndpointAddress adress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(@"https://apitest.merlion.com/rl/mlservice3"));
    ChannelFactory<MLPortChannel> factory = new ChannelFactory<MLPortChannel>(binding, adress);
    factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = mlLogin;
    factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = mlPassword;
    return factory.CreateChannel();
}
```

It is works correctly only for one method and returns the correct data type and the data.

When I call other methods, they returns error as:
"Can not convert an object of type " ... MLService3RLTest.CatalogResult [] " of the type " ... MLService3RLTest.ShipmentDatesResult []"

In this example return type must be ShipmentDatesResult[].

I tested the service via special tool. All requests and responses is correct and returned correct XML.

What may be the cause of this error? Perhaps something needs to be configured for SOAP service. Maybe some magic option with right value?

Answer (score 0):

If, instead of referring to the service, make a web link which uses the technology of web services .Net FrameWork 2.0 what works

```
var client = new WpfApplication1.com.merlion.apitest.MLService(); 
var myCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Логин, Пароль); 
// Create a webrequest with the specified URL. 

var url = "https://apitest.merlion.com/rl/mlservice3";;

client.Credentials = myCredentials.GetCredential(new Uri(url), "Basic");

textBox.AppendText(client.helloWorld("Привет"));

var ответ = client.getCatalog("N1");

var массив = new string[] { "" };

var rz = client.getItems("N10100", массив, "", 0, 2, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
client.PreAuthenticate = true;
```